# Is there a way to be inside a for loop, and then reverse that loop from the current position?

Tags: python, for-loop, reverse

For example, I have started coding an UNO! game I need to do the reverse card. The entire 'Main Game Code'where you place the card and re-sort the pile etc... The 'Main Game Code'is in this loop:
`while self.gamestr==True:
    for l in range(1,players+1):`

And I need the loop to be range(1,players+1,-1) whilst inside the loop and change it back again whilst still in the loop!
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: "==True" is unnecessary

Comment: do you need "break" or "continue"? Best you google for the usage

Comment: As far as i know reversing a loop is not possible. However, you could break the current loop and create a new loop with the matching criteria.

Comment: It's probably better to use a `while` here. You could technically do it with `for` and a weird iterator, but it'd probably make the control flow more confusing instead of less.

Comment: What will trigger the reversing of the loop in above code?

Comment: @ChetanGanji: If a player draws the reverse card, play goes from clockwise to counterclockwise (or vice versa).

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way to do what you want. You could *maybe* reverse the list in place, but you'd also need to shift parts of it to make sure the correct player is "next" in line.

A better choice is simply to use a different kind of loop. The easiest might be to use a `while` loop and keep track of the index you're on and the direction you're incrementing  in some variables that you can change:

```
players_list = range(1, players+1) # not actually a list in Python 3, but that doesn't matter
player_index = 0
player_direction = 1 # going forwards in the list, to start

while True:
    current_player = players_list[player_index]

    # do game stuff here with current_player

    if game_over:
        break

    if reverse:
        player_direction = -player_direction

    players_index = (players_index + player_direction) % players # update for next index
```

You might also be able to put some of that logic into a generator function. That would let you encapsulate the slightly messy logic of looping and reversing, and would let the main loop code just be `for player in player_gen()`. The only tricky thing would be figuring out how you'd have your game logic tell the generator when to reverse (and when to quit). If the generator was a method of some class (perhaps a `Game` class), it would be easy to use an attribute or method call to take care of things for you (the `game_over` variable could be `self.game_over`, and the flipping of `player_direction` could be in a `reverse` method).

Comment: Cool. This solution is better than breaking the current loop and creating a new one. It just modifies the current index.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a `demo` of how this could be done, when a wild card is drawn you can reconstruct your list that you are cycling by using slices and reverse step `[::-1]`

```
players = [1, 2, 3]
while True:
    for i, v in enumerate(players):
        if v == 1:
            print('wild card')
            players = players[i - 1::-1] + players[:i - 1:-1]
    print(players)
    for i, v in enumerate(players):
        if v == 3:
            print('wild card')
            players = players[i - 1::-1] + players[:i - 1:-1]
    print(players)
    break
```

> ```
> wild card
> [3, 2, 1]
> wild card
> [1, 2, 3]
> ```

Here we see if `wild` is on `player 1` then it becomes `player 3`'s turn playing in reverse, when `wild` is on `player 3` it reverse again and its on `player 1`. This is the general idea to apply to your game, this format is just for sake of demonstration.